# Como posso setar uma versão antiga do php no Xampp em localhost?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um curso de **PHP** e está aparecendo erros devido a versão **PHP** do Xampp ser mais atualizada que a versão **PHP** do curso.

***Pergunta***: É possível sem muita perda de tempo setar uma versão PHP anterior a que está sendo executada para sumir com estes erros de versão?

Comment: Se há erros, corrija-os.. O que quer fazer é como varrer sujeira para debaixo do tapete..  Dependendo dos tipos de erros, como os "warning errors" ou "deprecated error", é possível configurar em tempo de execução `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: Do not use deprecated functions!

Answer (score 5):

A resposta curta é: **não faça isso**.

O XAMPP é construído em volta de uma versão do PHP para garantir que tudo que vem como ele funcione corretamente. O mais adequado seria buscar uma "nova" versão dele com a versão do PHP que você deseja [aqui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/). (Estou assumindo que você esteja em ambiente windows)

**CHUTE**: Caso você realmente queira manter a sua versão do XAMPP, e alterar somente a versão do PHP, *eu acho* que você pode fazer o download dos binários que você deseja [aqui](http://php.net/downloads.php), e alterá-los na pasta do PHP que provavelmente está em `C:\xampp\php`, e depois alterar as suas configurações de acordo, mas confesso que isso deve trazer mais problemas do que soluções, isso se de fato funcionar. Meu conselho é que baixe uma versão (do XAMPP) correspondente estável.

Comment: atualizar os binários, de fato "deve trazer mais problemas do que soluções"